# Posting complex data dictionary with request python

Tags: python, django, post, request

I am posting data using post request.

```
   info={'abc':123, 'xyz':454, 'list':[{'test':33},{'test':44}]}
   request.post(url,data=info)
```

When i have posted above data, then its look like this in api

```
  <QueryDict: {u'abc': [u'123'], u'xyz': [u'454'], u'list': [u'test', u'test']}>
```

but i want my data in below format.

```
  <QueryDict: {u'abc': [u'123'], u'xyz': [u'454'], u'list': [u"[{'test':'33'},{'test':'44'}]"]}>
```

How should i achieve above format.

Comment: Try `request.post(url, data={key: str(value) for key, value in info.items()))`

Comment: You should make the working comment an answer and mark it as valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert each dict value to string (from @falsetru comment, edited to match brackets):

```
request.post(url, data={key: str(value) for key, value in info.items()})
```